# How to locate an XML error in python given the line number and column number?

Tags: python, xml

I am getting an error when I parse my xml. It gives a line and column number, but I am not sure how to go about locating it.

My code

```
urlBase = 'https://www.goodreads.com/review/list_rss/'
urlMiddle = '?shelf=read&order=d&sort=rating&per_page=200&page='
finalUrl = urlBase + str(32994) + urlMiddle +str(1)
resp = requests.get(finalUrl)
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
x = ET.fromstring(resp.content)
```

Error

```
  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 952, column 1023
```

I try to print the contents, but it's just one line

```
resp.content
```

The output is too big to print here.

So I'm not sure how to check a specific line since it's just one line.

Comment: Why don’t you write resp.content to a file, then open that file in an editor, then go to line 952 and right-cursor to column 1023?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a HTML content with an XML parser. You may run into problem if the content is not XML-valid: if it is not XHTML.

Instead of that, you can use a HTML parser like the one available with [lxml](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html).

For instance

```py
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(BytesIO(resp.content), parser)
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are on Windows and the print isn’t respecting e.g \n.

Try adding:

    `open(‘resp.xml’).write(resp.content)`

After where you get `resp`

Then, you can open resp.xml in an editor and see what line 952 looks like.